# What is the best way to detect if an element has a CSS animation applied

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, css-animations, web-component

I am attempting to fire an event on a [web component](https://github.com/john-doherty/pure-dialog) when a CSS animation has completed, however there is a possibility the user might clear the animation from the element using `animation: none;` meaning the `transitionend` event never fires:

```
// wait for dialog close animation to end before firing closed event
element.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {

    // fire dialog closed event
    self.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('pure-dialog-closed', { 
        bubbles: true, 
        cancelable: true 
    }));
});
```

To ensure my custom event always fires, I need to determine if the element or any of its children have an animation applied and if not, fire the `pure-dialog-closed` event immediately.

I have [tried](https://github.com/john-doherty/pure-dialog/blob/master/src/pure-dialog.js#L209) checking `style.animationName` and `self.style.transition` but it does not appear to be working. I need a simple way of checking if an element, or any of its children have a CSS animation applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you @Thusitha. I used `window.getComputedStyle` along with `animation-duration` and `transition-duration` to determine if an animation existed as either would need to be greater than 0s for an animation/transition to play out.

The following inspects all elements including element passed in:

```js
/**
 * Determine if an element of any or its children have a CSS animation applied
 * @param {HTMLElement} el - element to inspect
 * @returns {boolean} true if an animation/transition detected, otherwise false
 */
function hasCssAnimation(el) {

  // get a collection of all children including self
  var items = [el].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(el.getElementsByTagName("*")));

  // go through each item in reverse (faster)
  for (var i = items.length; i--;) {

    // get the applied styles
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(items[i], null);

    // read the animation/transition duration - defaults to 0
    var animDuration = parseFloat(style.getPropertyValue('animation-duration') || '0');
    var transDuration = parseFloat(style.getPropertyValue('transition-duration') || '0');

    // if we have any duration greater than 0, an animation exists
    if (animDuration > 0 || transDuration > 0) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

var elementToTest = document.querySelector('.one');
var result = hasCssAnimation(elementToTest);

alert(result);
```

```css
div {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.one {
  background: red;
}

.two {
  background: green;
  animation: zoomIn 3s ease; /* <-- animation applied to child */
}

.three {
  background: blue;
}

@keyframes zoomIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two"> <!-- animation on child element -->
    <div class="three">
      Hello World
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `getComputedStyle` function. Following is an example which read the `transition` property of a div.

Read more about this here.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

```js
function getTheStyle() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("elem-container");
  var theCSSprop = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("transition");
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = theCSSprop;
}

getTheStyle();
```

```css
#elem-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="elem-container"></div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for [animationend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend) and [animationstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationstart) events.

```js
let element = document.getElementById("square");

element.addEventListener("animationstart", function(event) {
  element.innerHTML = "RED!"
  element.setAttribute('data-animating', true);
}, false);

element.addEventListener("animationend", function(event) {
  element.innerHTML = "YELLOW!"
  element.setAttribute('data-animating', false);
}, false);

setInterval(() => {
  console.log(element.getAttribute('data-animating'))
}, 500)
```

```css
#square{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation-name: anim;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  background-color: red;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 100px;
}

@keyframes anim {
    to {background-color: yellow;}
}
```

```html
<div id="square"></div>
```